# windows firewall turns OFF automatically

Tags: windows, firewalls

It seems pretty weird but for some reason, the Windows 7 firewall turns off. After I turn the firewall on in the control panel, it seems that it turns itself off when I go back to the control after I reboot. Note that I'm using AVG Internet Security 2012 and Windows 7 x64 Pro.

Is this normal behavior? Is AVG turning the Windows Firewall off automatically?

Thanks for your suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[AVG Internet Security 2012](http://free.avg.com/us-en/free-internet-security) includes its own firewall function, and so yes, [it shuts down the Windows Firewall](http://forums.avg.com/us-en/avg-forums?sec=thread&act=show&id=210483) when it runs. Running multiple host firewalls on Windows is unpredictable and not recommended.

Comment: @Mark, You may want to elaboclarify on why *"Running multiple host firewalls on Windows is unpredictable"*

Answer (score 1):

In services.msc do you have the windows firewall process set to automatic? If it is set to manual it probably won't start at boot.

Comment: It's showing status started and startup type automatic. And yet the windows firewall is OFF.

Comment: no, please don't change to *automatically* when have 2 firewalls  = .. Norton turns off Windows Firewall :  please visit this site : https://community.norton.com/t5/Norton-360/Win-7-Reports-Norton-360-Firewall-and-Anti-Virus-Are-Turned-Off/m-p/785792/highlight/true#M77153

Answer (score 0):

When the AVG 2013 Firewall is turned ON, it turns OFF the Windows Firewall.  Without your approval, and without even telling you.

When the AVG 2013 Firewall is turned ***OFF***, it still turns OFF the Windows Firewall.  Again, Without your approval, and without even telling you.

You end up with *NO* Firewall at all.

Apparently, even ***HAVING*** the AVG 2013 Firewall installed is a very bad idea.